# Haskell error: Couldn't match type `a1' with `Int'

Tags: haskell, types, int

In haskell I have this function, which works great:

```
primesAtMost :: Integral a => a -> [a]
primesAtMost n = sieve [2..n]
where
    sieve :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
    sieve [] = []
    sieve (x:xs) = (x:sieve (filterMultiples x xs))
```

The problem is, it's parameter type is a, and I'm not allowed to change that.
When I try to call this function with a parameter that's type is Int, it gives an error: Couldn't match type `a1' with `Int'
For example:

```
primesAtMost (length n)
```

Comment: What's `filterMultiples`?

Comment: Your example compiles for me using ghc 8.2.2 and replacing `filterMultiples`with `undefined` (cause it is not in the code example)

Comment: And `n` in `length n` would be ...?

Comment: It's impossible to debug this without full information. You should post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).